# Kubuntu: no display configuration tool after upgrade from 12.10

Tags: kubuntu, display, kde

After upgrading Kubuntu from 12.10 to 13.04 there's no display configuration tool. I've installed `kscreen` package which wasn't selected during upgrade, but without any success.

I've dual screen setup, the configuration dialog for display is now empty.

[image: empty KDE display dialog]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, so installing `kscreen` seems to solve the issue:

```
apt-get install kscreen
```

The dialog is also available in KDE System Settings > Display and Monitor

[image: kscreen dialog]

The old configuration dialog which I've used to run from krunner by command `display` seems to be broken.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issues. After an upgrade from 12.10 > 13.04 > 13.10 I only had the screen locker settings present.

Comment: Your welcome, it probably happened to me during upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04. Hopefully with clean installation it will be ok, upgrades are always complicated.

Comment: Oh wow. Why is kscreen not installed by default?

Comment: In my Kubuntu 14.04 clean installation, kscreen was installed by default.